# Webforms routing with ASP.NET4

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, webforms

I need to provide a pageId on every URL however I don't need the user to see this pageId. For example

```
http://{domain}/{product-name}/{product-id}/{pageid} <-- I don't want to provide this
```

I have in my Global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("route-name", "path/{productName}/{product-id}", "~/ProductPage.aspx");
```

Is there some way to configure this route so it has a "hard coded" parameter page id for example something like this ---

```
routes.MapPageRoute("route-name", "path/{productName}/{product-id}", "~/ProductPage.aspx?pageid=1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some way to configure this route so it has a "hard coded"
>   parameter page id

Why yes... yes there is.

[MapPageRoute has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784594.aspx) that accepts a set of defaults for route values.

```
//Create route and set default values
routes.MapPageRoute(
   "route-name", 
   "path/{productName}/{product-id}", 
   "~/ProductPage.aspx",
   false,
   new RouteValueDictionary{
      {"product-id", 1}
   });
```

So now if you hit this route without a "product-id" specified, it will always default to `1`